# Getting a two dimensional array of all possible unique combination of numbers lower than a mixmum for each cell starting from 1

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq, math

Hello and thanks for your attention.

(my mathematical vocabulary for English language is rather limited, if you can think of a better title for this question please feel free to edit and thanks for help.)

I am trying to write a function that takes a One-dimensional array of numbers as an input and then returns a two dimensional array that contains all the potential combination of the all numbers lower or equal than their equivalent in input array starting from 1.

let me try to explain this better in two examples:

**example one:**

Input: `[2,3]`

Output:

```
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[2,1]
[2,2]
[2,3]
```

**example two:**

Input: `[2,3,2]`

Output:

```
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,2]
[1,3,1]
[1,3,2]
[2,1,1]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[2,2,2]
[2,3,1]
[2,3,2]
```

Also it would be great that you code returns order of arrays in the output in similar order of arrays in outputs in examples but that's not necessary.(the order of numbers inside arrays that are in the output is of course important!)

**Note:** the length of input array is unspecified and can contain any number of numbers.

**Note:** there is no need for output to be in array form and can be in form of common .NET collection like `List<double[]>` or `List<List<double>>` same goes for input.

If i can clarify the question better please tell in comment.

The following code is our attempt at solving this but it does not return all combinations and contain repetitions of arrays:

```
public class ArrayGenerator
{

    private int mainCounter;
    int count = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    private int movingCounter;
    public Dictionary<int, List<int>> series = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    public ArrayGenerator(params int[] args)
    {

        ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> listsCounter = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            listsCounter.TryAdd(i, 0);
            count *= args[i];
            var l = new List<int>();
            for (int j = 1; j <= args[i]; j++)
            {
                l.Add(j);
            }
            series.Add(i, l);
        }

        List<string> strs = new List<string>();
        while (mainCounter<count)
        {
            string str = "";
            counter = 0;
            while (counter < args.Length)
            {
                if (listsCounter[counter] < series[counter].Count)
                {
                    str += series[counter][listsCounter[counter]];
                    int c, d;
                    c = listsCounter[counter];
                    d = c + 1;
                    listsCounter.TryUpdate(counter, d, c);
                }
                else
                {
                    int c = listsCounter[counter];
                    listsCounter.TryUpdate(counter, 0,c);
                    str += series[counter][listsCounter[counter]];
                }

                counter++;
            }
            strs.Add(str);
            mainCounter++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like homework? Maybe they want you to use recursion...

Comment: @stickybit sadly it's not. it's for getting statistical data from a database, the output will later translate into address for rows in different tables. 2 programmers with total of 15 years experience has been working on this for 2 days and we couldn't reach a solution that wasn't buggy yet, it's starting to get embarrassing XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to create *jagged array* (i.e. *array of array*), `int[][]` then *2D* one `int[,]`:

```
using System.Linq;

... 

private static IEnumerable<int[]> Solution(int[] maxes) {
  if (null == maxes || maxes.Length <= 0 || maxes.Any(item => item < 1))
    yield break; // Or throw exception(s)

  int[] current = Enumerable
    .Repeat(1, maxes.Length)
    .ToArray();

  do {
    yield return current.ToArray(); // copy of current

    for (int i = current.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (current[i] < maxes[i]) {
        current[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
      else
        current[i] = 1;
  }
  while (!current.All(item => item == 1));
}

...

// Having an enumeration, we materialize it as an array, i.e. array of array
int[][] demo = Solution(new int[] { 2, 3, 2})
  .ToArray();

// Let's have a look at the results
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  demo.Select(line => string.Join(", ", line))));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
1, 2, 1
1, 2, 2
1, 3, 1
1, 3, 2
2, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
2, 2, 1
2, 2, 2
2, 3, 1
2, 3, 2
```

If you insist on **2D** array, you can convert:

```
  int[,] data2D = new int[demo.Length, demo.Length > 0 ? demo[0].Length : 0];

  for (int y = 0; y < demo.Length; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < demo[0].Length; ++x)
      data2D[y, x] = demo[y][x];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! i experimented with jagged array as well,  the codes that delivers the input for this function and required the output which require arrays wasn't written by me, although to be fair i also probably would have used 2D array. jagged arrays are one of those things that most people don't think of unless they get stumped :)